# Using TogetherJS Extensibility to Sync Changes to a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to add some code around TogetherJS to enable the synchronization (between TogetherJS users) of changes that are being made to a contenteditable div.

My question is how I could do this for a div - which seems like it would be a much easier functionality to implement but I can't currently wrap my head around it.

TogetherJS developers provided an example of how to do this for drawing on a canvas:

```
<canvas id="sketch" 
    style="height: 400px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid #000">
</canvas>

// get the canvas element and its context
var canvas = document.querySelector('#sketch');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// brush settings
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.lineJoin = 'round';
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.strokeStyle = '#000';
```

We’ll use mousedown and mouseup events on the canvas to register our move() handler for the mousemove event:

```
var lastMouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

// attach the mousedown, mousemove, mouseup event listeners.
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
lastMouse = {
    x: e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
    y: e.pageY - this.offsetTop
};
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
}, false);
```

And then the move() function will figure out the line that needs to be drawn:

```
function move(e) {
var mouse = {
    x: e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
    y: e.pageY - this.offsetTop
};
draw(lastMouse, mouse);
lastMouse = mouse;
}
```

And lastly a function to draw lines:

```
function draw(start, end) {
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
context.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
}
```

This is enough code to give us a very simple drawing application. TogetherJS has a “hub” that echoes messages between everyone in the session. It doesn’t interpret messages, and everyone’s messages travel back and forth, including messages that come from a person that might be on another page. TogetherJS also lets the application send their own messages like:

```
TogetherJS.send({
  type: "message-type", 
  ...any other attributes you want to send...
})
```

to send a message (every message must have a type), and to listen:

```
TogetherJS.hub.on("message-type", function (msg) {
  if (! msg.sameUrl) {
      // Usually you'll test for this to discard messages that came
      // from a user at a different page
      return;
  }
});
```

The message types are namespaced so that your application messages won’t accidentally overlap with TogetherJS’s own messages.

To synchronize drawing we’d want to watch for any lines being drawn and send those to the other peers:

```
function move(e) {
    var mouse = {
        x: e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y: e.pageY - this.offsetTop
    };
    draw(lastMouse, mouse);
    if (TogetherJS.running) {
        TogetherJS.send({type: "draw", start: lastMouse end: mouse});
    }
    lastMouse = mouse;
}
```

Before we send we check that TogetherJS is actually running (TogetherJS.running). The message we send should be self-explanatory.

Next we have to listen for the messages:

```
TogetherJS.hub.on("draw", function (msg) {
    if (! msg.sameUrl) {
        return;
    }
    draw(msg.start, msg.end);
});
```

We don’t have to worry about whether TogetherJS is running when we register this listener, it can only be called when TogetherJS is running.

This is enough to make our drawing live and collaborative. But there’s one thing we’re missing: if I start drawing an image, and you join me, you’ll only see the new lines I draw, you won’t see the image I’ve already drawn.

To handle this we’ll listen for the togetherjs.hello message, which is the message each client sends when it first arrives at a new page. When we see that message we’ll send the other person an image of our canvas:

```
TogetherJS.hub.on("togetherjs.hello", function (msg) {
    if (! msg.sameUrl) {
        return;
    }
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    TogetherJS.send({
        type: "init",
        image: image
    });
});
```

Now we just have to listen for this new init message:

```
TogetherJS.hub.on("init", function (msg) {
    if (! msg.sameUrl) {
        return;
    }
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = msg.image;
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Which *specific* part of this tutorial are you having trouble adapting? Presumably you need to a) change your message structure to send the content or changes to the div, b) replace the draw method with a method that will update the div c) attach a handler to your contentEditable to send messages whenever the content is changed... But we're not here to write code for you... posting someone else's tutorial is not a good practice and at the moment your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Based off of other TogetherJS posts, I wasn't even sure someone would respond. My idea currently is to take the innerhtml of the div and send that as the message. Do you think that's a good approach (provided that I want the html from that div in addition to the text)?
Preferably, I'd like it this to sync with every keyup but I'm afraid syncing the entire thing would be too cumbersome on every keyup - but maybe there's an approach that I'm not thinking of...
I definitely understand what you're saying btw - I don't want anyone to write code - hopefully my elaboration above helps with context.

Comment: synching on every keyup sounds crazy! (considering the frequency of keyups vs network latency)! Instead I'd probably set a dirty flag whenever there is a keyup, then use setInterval() every 5 seconds or so, and during setInterval() callback send a message if the dirty flag is true... then after sending the message set the dirty flag to false.

Comment: That's a good call. I'll have to tool around with that a bit. Thanks, man.

Comment: The biggest problem you might get though is if there are concurrent edits to the content by multiple users. Handling this is never simple in any multi-user scenario with latency

Comment: Fortunately, in this scenario, I'd have 2 people using the app simultaneously - highly unlikely that there would be more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked surprisingly well for me - awesome performance (although this is for an intranet site).

For beginners (like me) to extending TogetherJS to your own apps, the "type" can be set to anything. It helps distinguish the function of this particular message/action pair from others. It is required as it is basically the title of the message. For "output", you can also name that anything (or have more than one). That will store data to be sent with the message.

The first section of code sends the message.

The second section of code listens for the message from other TogetherJS users on the same shared URL. The naming conventions between the "send" and "listen" events/functions *must* match (e.g., text-send)

Here is my solution:

```
$('#SourceText').keyup(function (event) {
    // grab text for sending as a message to collaborate
    var sharedtext = $('#SourceText').html()
    //alert(sharedtext)
    if (TogetherJS.running) {
        TogetherJS.send({
            type: "text-send",
            output: sharedtext
        });
        console.log(sharedtext)
    }
});

TogetherJS.hub.on("text-send", function (msg) {
    if (! msg.sameUrl) {
        return;
    }
    $('#SourceText').html(msg.output);
    console.log(msg.output)
});
```